# Converter formato de data DD/MM/YYYY para YYYY-MM-DD guardado em um varchar

Tags: mysql

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

O campo `data` é do tipo do `varchar`, no mês de junho o formato da data é `DD/MM/YYYY`, mas queria muda-lo para `YYYY-MM-DD` já que é o formato que MySQL aceita e para seguir o padrão atual de julho.
Depois que eu mudar para o formato correto, gostaria de mudar a coluna `data` para o tipo `DATE` . Que tipo de tratamento devo fazer?

Answer (score 4):

Baseado no fato de que você quer atualizar diretamente o banco, segue um update onde utilizando a funcao SUBSTR do mysql em todos os registros que não contem "/".

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo_data = CONCAT(SUBSTR(campo_data,7,4),'-',SUBSTR(campo_data,4,2),'-',SUBSTR(campo_data,1,2)) 
WHERE campo_data LIKE '%/%'
```

Por exemplo:

> Campo data = 13/06/2015
>
> SUBSTR(campo_data,7,4) = 2015 //4 posicoes a partir do 7 caractere
>
> SUBSTR(campo_data,4,2) = 06  //2 posicoes a partir do 4 caractere
>
> SUBSTR(campo_data,1,2) =  13 //2 posicoes a partir do 1 caractere
>
> Depois foi só concatenar no formato desejado (ANO-MES-DIA):
>   CONCAT(SUBSTR(campo_data,7,4),'-',SUBSTR(campo_data,4,2),'-',SUBSTR(campo_data,1,2))

Comment: Poderia completar sua resposta mostrando o que está usando para responder a pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Se você está recebendo a data do mysql e quer converter para o formato brasileiro use o seguinte comando:

```
$data = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
```

Isto vai criar a data do mysql em formato brasileiro.

Se você quer preparar a data em formato brasileiro para inserir no mysql use:

```
$data = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
```

Comment: na verdade eu queria mudar os valores que estão salvos no banco de dados e transforma-los a data que estava em junho no formato YYYY-MM-DD, depois eu vou mudar a coluna para o tipo DATE já que atualmente está como varchar.

Comment: Com esse trecho de código que coloquei, você consegue converter os formatos de data. Depois é só salvar no banco.

Answer (score 2):

O @pedroAugusto deu uma boa resposta, mas o que ele disse também pode ser feita de uma maneira orientada a objetos. É uma solução que já é do próprio PHP, através da classe `DateTime`.

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);

$datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```