# Problema na inserção de dados na tabela mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com um problema para inserir dados em uma tabela alguém pode me mostrar o erro.

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form method="POST" action="varcadastro.php">
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="name">Nome</label>
      </p>
      <input id="name" name="nome" placeholder="Primeiro e Ultimo nome" type="text">

      <p class="contact">
        <label for="datanasc">Data Nascimento</label>
      </p>
      <input id="email" name="datanasc" placeholder="22041996" type="date">
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="username">Usuario</label>
      </p>
      <input id="username" name="usuario" placeholder="usuario" type="text">
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="password">Senha</label>
      </p>
      <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha">
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="cpf">cpf</label>
      </p>
      <input id="cpf" name="cpf" type="cpf">
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="cidade">cidade</label>
      </p>
      <input id="cidade" name="cidade" type="cidade" <p class="contact">
      <label for="bairro">bairro</label>
      </p>
      <input id="bairro" name="bairro" type="bairro">

      <p class="contact">
        <label for="rua">rua</label>
      </p>
      <input id="rua" name="rua" type="rua">
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="numero">numero</label>
      </p>
      <input id="numero" name="numero" type="numero">
      <p class="contact">
        <label>Telefone Residencial</label>
      </p>
      <input name="telefone1" placeholder="phone number" type="text">
      <br>
      <p class="contact">
        <label>Telefone Celular</label>
      </p>
      <input id="phone" name="telefone2" placeholder="phone number" type="text">
      <br>
      <p class="contact">
        <label for="phone">Telefone Opcional</label>
      </p>
      <input id="phone" name="telefone3" placeholder="phone number" type="text">
      <br>
      <input name="submit" value="Cadastrar" type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $nome= $_POST["nome"];
    $datanasc= $_POST["datanasc"];
    $rua= $_POST["rua"];
    $usuario= $_POST["usuario"];
    $senha= $_POST["senha"];
    $cpf= $_POST["cpf"];
    $numero= $_POST["numero"];
    $cidade= $_POST["cidade"];
    $telefone1= $_POST["telefone1"];
    $telefone2= $_POST["telefone2"];
    $telefone3= $_POST["telefone3"];
    $bairro= $_POST["bairro"];
    $conexao = @mysql_connect("localhost","root"); //localhost é onde esta o banco de dados.
if (!$conexao)
die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
 //conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("biblioteca",$conexao); //nome da tabela que deseja que seja inserida os dados cadastrais
if (!$banco)
die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO `manterusuario` (`nome`, `telefone1`, `telefone2`, `telefone3`, `cpf`, `datanasc`, `usuario`, `senha` , `cidade` , `rua` , `bairro` , numero` ) VALUES (`$nome`, `$telefone1`, `$telefone2`, `$telefone3`, `$cpf`, `$datanasc`, `$usuario`, `$senha` , `$cidade` , `$rua` , `$bairro` , $numero` )";
mysql_query($query,$conexao);
echo "Cadatro realizado com sucesso!Obrigado!";
?>
```

Minha tabela está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE manterusuario (
  codigousuario INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  manterbiblioteca_codigobiblioteca INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  telefone1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  telefone2 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  telefone3 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  cpf VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  datanasc DATE NOT NULL,
  login VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  senha VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  cidade VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  rua VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  bairro VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  numero VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(codigousuario),
  INDEX manter_usuario_FKIndex1(manterbiblioteca_codigobiblioteca)
);
```

Comment: Todos os campos da sua tabela sao varchar?

Comment: Alias, poste a modelagem da sua tabela `manterusuario ` ai.

Comment: Marcelo, clique em [edit] e adicione na pergunta.

Comment: Boa noite Marcelo, não entendi, usou a tag mysqli, mas teu código nada tem com a API MYSQLI do php, isto é confuso. Diga qual erro ocorre?

Comment: No SQL do INSERT perto do final, este `, $numero\`` com o `\`` no final mas não no começo é muito suspeito, você não acha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não utilize as funções `mysql_*` ela estão obsoletas e foram removidas do php7, não utilize `@` ela oculta os erros o que dificulta a detecção do problema.

Se estiver um projeto legando tudo bem, sempre adicione `or die(mysql_error())` junto com o `mysql_query()` assim é possível saber se o erro é no banco ou no código php.

O problema do seu insert é backtick(``` `` ```) são usados somente em nome da tabelas ou colunas e não em valores. Depois do `values` troque os backticks por aspas simples(`'`)

Errado:

```
INSERT INTO `manterusuario` (`nome`, `telefone1`, `telefone2`, `telefone3`, `cpf`, `datanasc`, `usuario`, `senha` , `cidade` , `rua` , `bairro` , `numero` )
 VALUES (`$nome`, `$telefone1`, `$telefone2`, `$telefone3`, `$cpf`, 
`$datanasc`, `$usuario`, `$senha` , `$cidade` , `$rua` , `$bairro` , $numero` )
```

Certo:

```
INSERT INTO `manterusuario` (`nome`, `telefone1`, `telefone2`, `telefone3`, `cpf`, `datanasc`, `usuario`, `senha` , `cidade` , `rua` , `bairro` , `numero` ) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$telefone1', '$telefone2', '$telefone3', '$cpf', '$datanasc', '$usuario', '$senha' , '$cidade' , '$rua' , '$bairro' , '$numero' )
```

Se precisar conveter a data de `d/m/Y` para `Y-m-d` veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76862/91)

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

Comment: Sem contar que ele está adicionando a data do jeito que ela está vindo no formato BR, e não no formato correto do banco.

Comment: Vlw ja consegui aqui

Comment: @MarceloGomes Se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta, obrigado!